# Is there a way to request a specific dataset from a rest api?

Tags: json, yaml

Sorry if this seems dumb to some of you, I am a total noob and literally have no idea what I'm trying to google, so I can't even try googling this before I ask.

I would like to pull specifically england covid19 data from this page:  https://services1.arcgis.com/0MSEUqKaxRlEPj5g/arcgis/rest/services/Coronavirus_2019_nCoV_Cases/FeatureServer/1/query?where=1%3D1&outFields=*&outSR=4326&f=json

and then set it as a json attribute (if possible).

I'm trying to create a sensor in Home Assistant for England Covid19 data, using the rest platform.

I am taking this idea from someone else who has already successfully acheived this:

- platform: rest
  name: covid_19_folkhalsomyndigheten
  resource: https://www.arcgis.com/sharing/rest/content/items/2dc63e26f509468f896ec69476b0dab3/data
  value_template: "{% if value_json.embedCode == '' %} Otillgänglig {% else %} Tillgänglig {% endif %}"
  json_attributes_path: $.widgets.widget_1.config
  json_attributes: [embedCode]
  scan_interval: 21600

But there are differences in the actual resource he is using and mine so maybe I cannot just copy his method.

If anyone has the spare time to guide me through this I would be very greatful. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Here ya go, here's an answer using python3

```
import json
import requests # you'll have to install this with something like pip

r=requests.get('https://services1.arcgis.com/0MSEUqKaxRlEPj5g/arcgis/rest/services/Coronavirus_2019_nCoV_Cases/FeatureServer/1/query?where=1%3D1&outFields=*&outSR=4326&f=json')

print(r.text, ' this will be your json object')

# if you want to write the data to a file called data.txt (note you can choose any name like corona.txt)
with open('data.txt', 'w') as outfile:
    json.dump(r.text, outfile)
```

The following code would fetch the data, and then write and create a file called data.txt